# Call extension method in Cocos3D

Tags: objective-c, cocos3d

I am new in Objective C, I am trying to create some 3d models using Cocos3d I found this documentation:

```
/**
 * This CC3Mesh extension adds a number of methods for populating the mesh of
 * a mesh programatically to create various parametric shapes and surfaces.
 *
 * To use the methods in this extension, instantiate a CC3Mesh, and then invoke one of
 * the methods in this extension  to populate the mesh vertices.
 */
@interface CC3Mesh (ParametricShapes)
```

and this is the method I want to invoke:

```
-(void) populateAsTriangle: (CC3Face) face
             withTexCoords: (ccTex2F*) texCoords
           andTessellation: (GLuint) divsPerSide;
```

and now I have this:

```
    NSString *meshName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", 
                               [vertex objectForKey:@"meshName"]];
    CC3Mesh *mesh = [[CC3Mesh alloc] initWithName:meshName];
```

Now, how do I call the method populateAsTriangle from my *mesh object?

Thanks.

Comment: The same way you would call any other method on that object...

Comment: when I try to do it like:

[mesh populateAsTriangle: cc3face withTexCoords: texCoords andTessellation: 1]; I got the warning: -populateAsTriangle:withTexCoords:andTessellation:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')

Comment: it may be a private method you're not supposed to use, this is the case when the method is not declared in the header (within @interface)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you import the file where the `CC3Mesh` extension you reference is located:

```
#import "CC3ParametricMeshes.h"
```

Comment: Thanks you Bill, it was a completely newbie issue.